# Argument data type varchar(max) is invalid for argument 1 of Decompress function

Tags: c#, sql-server, gzip, compression

I am saving my string values as `GZIP` into a SQL Server 2016 `VARCHAR(max)` column.

Converting string into `GZIP` form is done by using C#.

An example value

```
This is my trial string
```

The produced GZIP value

```
FwAAAB+LCAAAAAAABAALycgsVgCi3EqFkqLMxByFYiCVlw4AJnX75BcAAAA=
```

Is that possible to select this value as unzipped from SQL Server?

Or do I have to unzip it inside my C# application?

I have tried the following function but it fails. Tried as `NVARCHAR(max)` as well

[image]

The gzip function i use

```
public static string GZip_String(string text)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress, true))
        {
            gZipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        memoryStream.Position = 0;

        var compressedData = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
        memoryStream.Read(compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);


        var gZipBuffer = new byte[compressedData.Length + 4];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(compressedData, 0, gZipBuffer, 4, compressedData.Length);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gZipBuffer, 0, 4);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(gZipBuffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The Decompress function works against binary data, so you might try storing your bytes in a varbinary field. Here's how it works in pure SQL (haven't tried it from C#):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    F1 varchar(100)
  , F2 varbinary(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO #tmp
(
    F1
  , F2
)
VALUES
    ('Hey there.'           -- F1 - varchar(100)
   , COMPRESS('Hey there.') -- F2 - varbinary(max)
    );

SELECT F1
     , F2
     , CAST(DECOMPRESS(F2) AS varchar(100))
  FROM #tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the data type of Compressed field in your table is not valid and you should change it to varbinary(MAX).
when you use Compress function wrong type of field cause no exception (for example nvarchar(MAX)) but when you want to use decompress function it will cause this error.

you can simply change your field's data type and rerun the query.

Comment: Helpful to know that compress works without error with, for example, json in an nvarchar(max) field, but then you can't decompress it. +1